# Comparacion de registros mysql con array php

Tags: php, mysql, array

Necesito comparar los id contenidos dentro de un array php, con los de un campo de una tabla mysql. La idea es NO mostrar los id (del array php) en la respuesta de la consulta mysql.

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM permisos_pedidos WHERE id_cliente = '$id_us' AND id = '$trat'";
$ejecutar_consulta = $conexion->query($consulta);
$perm = array();
while ($registro = $ejecutar_consulta->fetch_assoc())
{
    $perm[] = $registro["etapas"];
}
```

$perm es mi array que contiene los id de los usuarios.
Ahora, lo que necesito, es que en otra consulta, no me muestre los id de los usuarios que estan en $perm. Lo que me muestra el array (lo cual es correcto):

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "9" [1]=> string(2) "10" }
```

Donde 9 y 10 son los id que no debo mostra en la siguiente consulta.
Alguna idea de como hacer esta comparacion?.
Como siempre, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Quieres una consulta que saque lo contrario de lo que te saca la que tienes ahora?

Comment: Podrías ser un poco más enfática en lo que quieres? Quiero colaborar pero no entiendo a ciencia cierta que es lo que necesitas. Quieres excluir en tu 2da consulta los valores de la primera o que necesitas?

Comment: Deberías ser un poco más claro en lo que pides

Answer (score 1):

imagino que lo que quieres es sacar de la tabla permisos_pedidos, los permisos de usuarios diferentes a los que has pedido en la primera consulta, si es así la forma mas sencilla sería la siguiente:

```
"$consulta = select * FROM permisos_pedidos WHERE id_cliente not in (". implode(',', $perm ). ")"
```

Espero que el id_cliente sea el discriminante que quieres usar, igualmente, la idea sería esa, usar un not in para buscar los que no están dentro de un conjunto, en este caso la lista de ids de la variable $perm.

espero esto te ayude.

Saludos